# Convert XML to CSV file

Tags: python, xml, csv, xpath, elementtree

I have an XML file like this:

```xml
<hierachy>
    <att>
        <Order>1</Order>
        <attval>Data</attval>
        <children>
            <att>
                <Order>1</Order>
                <attval>Studyval</attval>
            </att>
            <att>
                <Order>2</Order>
                <attval>Site</attval>
            </att>
        </children>
    </att>
    <att>
        <Order>2</Order>
        <attval>Info</attval>
        <children>
            <att>
                <Order>1</Order>
                <attval>age</attval>
            </att>
            <att>
                <Order>2</Order>
                <attval>gender</attval>
            </att>
        </children>
    </att>
</hierachy>
```

I'm trying to convert it to a CSV file like this:

```
Data,Studyval
Date,Site
Info,age
Info,gender
```

My problem is, both the parent and child names are the same - `'att'` and `'attval'`. How do I tell Python to distinguish between them both and give me the output?

I tried this:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
rebase = tree.getroot()

list = []

for att in rebase.findall('att'):
        name = att.find('attval').text
        for each_att in att.findall('attval'):
            try:
                val = att.find('attval').text
                print name, val
            except AttributeError:
                print name
```

and it printed the same things twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not use the `findall` function, as it will look for att tags in the whole tree. Just iterate the tree in order from top to bottom and grab the relevant elements in them.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for att in root:
    first = att.find('attval').text
    for subatt in att.find('children'):
        second = subatt.find('attval').text
        print('{},{}'.format(first, second))
```

Which gives:

```
$ python process.py 
Data,Studyval
Data,Site
Info,age
Info,gender
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks a ton!