# How to loop through XML rows?

Tags: python, xml, loops, tags

I have an xml structure like so :

```xml
<Resident Id="100">
    <Name>Sample Name</Name>
    <PhoneNumber>12345642357891</PhoneNumber>
    <EmailAddress>sample_name@example.com</EmailAddress>
    <Address>
        <StreetLine1>Street Line1</StreetLine1>
        <City>City Name</City>
        <StateCode>AE</StateCode>
        <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
    </Address>
</Resident>
```

I want to loop through each row and while I can do the below (snippet)

```
for element in root:
    listOfAttribAndValues = []
    listOfAttribAndValues.append(int(element.get("Id")))
    listOfAttribAndValues.append(element.find('Name').text)
    #and so on and then write them to a list, and then write the list to a csv file
    writer.writerow(listOfAttribAndValues)
```

Is there an easy way to loop through each row (`Name`, `PhoneNumber`, etc) rather than explicitly finding the value of each item out?

Comment: I don't think so because XML has no concept of "rows" — in terms of non-quoted whitespace, it's free-form.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct. As mentioned in the comments, there is no concept of XML "rows". XML is a tree. The items are associated with their parent elements and child elements, but not with each other. In fact, no particular order is guaranteed or expected among elements of the same depth in the tree.

The answer here may help improve your code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31844901/2713818