# Effective way to convert an XML file to a CSV file?

Tags: python, xml, csv, type-conversion, elementtree

I am trying to find a way to convert an xml file to a csv file with Python. I would like to do it so that the script will parse the xml file with each alarm (please see the xml snippet below).

So it would make an xls file with columns for `eventType`, `probableCause`, `description`, and `severities` kind of similar to this format:

[image: screenshot showing format]

The code I have doesn't work, it only updates the column names.

XML sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faults version="1" xmlns="urn:nortel:namespaces:mcp:faults" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:nortel:namespaces:mcp:faults NortelFaultSchema.xsd ">
    <family longName="1OffMsgr" shortName="OOM"/>
    <family longName="ACTAGENT" shortName="ACAT">
        <logs>
           <log>
                <eventType>RES</eventType>
                <number>1</number>
                <severity>INFO</severity>
                <descTemplate>
                     <msg>Accounting is enabled upon this NE.</msg>
               </descTemplate>
               <note>This log is generated when setting a Session Manager's AM from &lt;none&gt; to a valid AM.</note>
               <om>On all instances of this Session Manager, the &lt;NE_Inst&gt;:&lt;AM&gt;:STD:acct OM row in the  StdRecordStream group will appear and start counting the recording units sent to the configured AM.
                   On the configured AM, the &lt;NE_inst&gt;:acct OM rows in RECSTRMCOLL group will appear and start counting the recording units received from this Session Manager's instances.
               </om>
            </log>
           <log>
                <eventType>RES</eventType>
                <number>2</number>
                <severity>ALERT</severity>
                <descTemplate>
                     <msg>Accounting is disabled upon this NE.</msg>
               </descTemplate>
               <note>This log is generated when setting a Session Manager's AM from a valid AM to &lt;none&gt;.</note>
               <action>If you do not intend for the Session Manager to produce accounting records, then no action is required.  If you do intend for the Session Manager to produce accounting records, then you should set the Session Manager's AM to a valid AM.</action>
               <om>On all instances of this Session Manager, the &lt;NE_Inst&gt;:&lt;AM&gt;:STD:acct OM row in the StdRecordStream group that matched the previous datafilled AM will disappear.
                   On the previously configured AM, the  &lt;NE_inst&gt;:acct OM rows in RECSTRMCOLL group will disappear.
               </om>
            </log>
        </logs>
    </family>
    <family longName="ACODE" shortName="AC">
        <alarms>
            <alarm>
                <eventType>ADMIN</eventType>
                <number>1</number>
                <probableCause>INFORMATION_MODIFICATION_DETECTED</probableCause>
                <descTemplate>
                    <msg>Configured data for audiocode server updated: $1</msg>
                     <param>
                         <num>1</num>
                         <description>AudioCode configuration data got updated</description>
                         <exampleValue>acgwy1</exampleValue>
                     </param>
               </descTemplate>
               <manualClearable></manualClearable>
               <correctiveAction>None. Acknowledge/Clear alarm and deploy the audiocode server if appropriate.</correctiveAction>
               <alarmName>Audiocode Server Updated</alarmName>
               <severities>
                     <severity>MINOR</severity>
               </severities>               
            </alarm>
            <alarm>
                <eventType>ADMIN</eventType>
                <number>2</number>
                <probableCause>CONFIG_OR_CUSTOMIZATION_ERROR</probableCause>
                <descTemplate>
                    <msg>Deployment for audiocode server failed: $1. Reason: $2.</msg>
                     <param>
                         <num>1</num>
                         <description>AudioCode Name</description>
                         <exampleValue>audcod</exampleValue>
                     </param>
                     <param>
                         <num>2</num>
                         <description>AudioCode Deployment failed reason</description>
                         <exampleValue>Failed to parse audiocode configuration data</exampleValue>
                     </param>
               </descTemplate>
               <manualClearable></manualClearable>
               <correctiveAction>Check the configuration of audiocode server. Acknowledge/Clear alarm and deploy the audiocode server if appropriate.</correctiveAction>
               <alarmName>Audiocode Server Deploy Failed</alarmName>
               <severities>
                     <severity>MINOR</severity> 
               </severities>               
            </alarm>
        </alarms>
    </family>
</faults>
```

What I've tried (small sample):

```
from logging import root
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import os
import csv

tree = ElementTree.parse('Fault.xml')

sitescope_data = open('Out.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
csvwriter = csv.writer(sitescope_data)

col_names = ['eventType', 'probableCause', 'description']
csvwriter.writerow(col_names)

root = tree.getroot()
for eventData in root.findall('alarms'):
    event_data = []
    event = eventData.find('alarm')


    event_id = event.find('eventType')
    if event_id != None :
        event_id = event_id.text
    event_data.append(event_id)

    csvwriter.writerow(event_data)

sitescope_data.close()
```

Comment: Does this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844713/python-convert-xml-to-csv-file help?

Comment: I can't get it to work, its only updating the column names @martineau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
root = tree.getroot()

def get_uri(elem):
    if elem.tag[0] == "{":
        uri, ignore, tag = elem.tag[1:].partition("}")
        return f"{{{uri}}}"
    return ""

uri = get_uri(root)

def recurse(root):
    for child in root:
        recurse(child)
        print(child.tag)
    for event in root.findall(f'{uri}alarm'):
        event_data = []
        event_id = event.find(f'{uri}eventType')
        if event_id != None :
            event_id = event_id.text
        event_data.append(event_id)

        probableCause = event.find(f'{uri}probableCause')
        if probableCause != None:
            probableCause = probableCause.text
        event_data.append(probableCause)

        severities = event.find(f'{uir}severities')
        if severities:
            severity_data = ','.join([sv.text for sv in severities.findall('f{uri}severity')])
            event_data.append(severity_data)
        else:
            event_data.append("")

        csvwriter.writerow(event_data)
        

recurse(root)
```

To things to note:

1. Use recursion to walk through XML
2. The print statement will show you that your tags each have {urn:nortel:namespaces:mcp:faults} coming from the xmlns attribute in the root which is probably most of what was tripping you up.
   I added a function to get this "uri" text and prepend it to each tag.
3. you will want to be appending more than one column each time you write to csv

Comment: No problem, BTW, next time, when you post xml, make sure you post the whole file or close all the tags to keep a poor sod like me from having to close them while trying to find your issue.- Cheers

Comment: I think I'm having a bit of trouble moving to the next column and writing the next data to the csv ('probableCause' from the xml). Do you think you could briefly explain how I should do that properly if you have time?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Probable cause is easy, and I updated the code to show it. The  description is the tricky one as you have to do argument replacement

Comment: aah ok. Also with 'severity' since it's embedded in 'severities', do I have to make another for loop in order to reach it?

Comment: Yes you will need to loop through each severity in severities and put them in a single string with commas

Comment: Hey @Techniquab, do you mind if I ask you another question building on to this? I posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64031471/parsing-an-xml-file-to-convert-to-a-csv