# save response from API to csv file

Tags: python, api, csv, httplib2

I am a new learner to python.  I am working with some python code that calls an api and get a response in csv format.  I would like to know how can I save that csv response to a csv fie.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import httplib2
# These aren't needed, just for this example
from pprint import pformat

from datetime import datetime
import pytz

from pvlive_api import PVLive

import pandas as pd
import json


def post_elexon(url):
    http_obj = httplib2.Http()
    resp, content = http_obj.request(
        uri=url,
        method='GET',
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8'},)
    return resp, content

def main():
    resp, content = post_elexon(url='https://api.bmreports.com/BMRS/B1770/v1?APIKey=MY_API_KEY&SettlementDate=2015-03-01&Period=1&ServiceType=csv',)
    print ("===Response===")
    print (resp)
    
    print ("===Content===")
    print (pformat(content))
    print ("===Finished===")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any help, advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: See [Reading and Writing CSV Files in Python](https://realpython.com/python-csv/) or the canonical [CSV documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    import csv
    
    with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(resp)
        for line in resp.iter_lines():
            writer.writerow(line.decode('utf-8').split(','))
```

**Edit:**

I tested your request - it returns a json.

so you can save it as json:

```
with open('response.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(resp, f)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I get error: argument 1 must have "write" method.   Where should the code thats starts: with open.....   be placed?

Comment: Many thnaks for this, it does not create any error but where does the json file get created/saved?

Comment: ignore my last comment, I can see it, can I set the location where the json is saved if I give a file path to the out.csv  eg  with open('C:\Test\response.json)

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I really appreciate it.  If I wanted to write the content returned by the api call (content) to a csv file - how woud that be acheived?

Comment: Your content is in XML format. I do not have a valid API key to read the real content and its attributes. Have a look at these: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-xml-to-csv-in-python/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844713/convert-xml-to-csv-file to convert XML to csv. good luck. (:

Comment: Thanks again.  I found an example that I could use here: https://pybit.es/download-xml-file.html